# Changing the Default EventHandler Naming in VS2012

Tags: c#, naming-conventions, visual-studio-2012

There is an excellent extension for VS2010 that allows the user to change the default naming of event handlers:  http://einaregilsson.com/better-eventhandler-names-in-visual-studio-2010/

I really dislike (irrationally I am sure) the default names generated by VS2012 which I think are the same as earlier versions.  For example:

```
myMenuItem_Click(..)
```

and I much prefer something like

```
onMyMenuItemClick(..)
```

So far Einar has not updated his extension for VS2012 - I hope he will...

I have had a bit of a look around in options for VS2012 without seeing anything obvious.  As far as I can tell ReSharper might tell me the underscore is bad practice but doesn't allow me to over write the default.  I am a bit nervious of digging around too much so if anyone can point me in the right direction or put me out of my misery then I can at least move onto another worry....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a comment in that blog post from late August 2012 saying Einar will try for VS 2012 support.  Maybe email and ask how you can help?

Otherwise, I'd suggest downloading the GPL'd code for 2010 and start digging in.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I would still be interested in knowing if there is any 'official' way to do this in VS2012 though....